# Cross-domain PUT without CORS

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, gdata, cors, gdata-api

My client-only javascript app wants to use the gdata API.  Gdata writes are PUTs.

I can read gdata using JSONP.  Simple.

I can POST because form-posts are not governed by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  I could even do [something cute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925260/how-to-use-iframe-to-cross-domain-post-request) with the form.

But my API doesn't want POST, it wants PUT.

How can I PUT cross-domain, client-side only, without CORS (because gdata does not support CORS)?

---

an update: as a hail-mary, i tried overriding the verb, [as instructed,](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/basics) using `X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT` in a jquery XHR POST, but that doesn't work; XHR respects the same-origin policy for POST.

Answer (score 0):

Which API are you using? You could try using either the [GData JavaScript client](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-javascript-client/) (which is deprecated) or the newer [Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/). Depending on which API you are querying, the latter may or may not support it.

Comment: i used the 'client library for javascript' for authentication, but this library doesn't support the spreadsheet api.  i'm using the jquery ajax thing to actually make requests, using the auth token returned by the 'client library for javascript'